# looping multidimensional array into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a multi dimensional array that have a structure like this

```
[nmbr] => Array
       (
           [0] => u
           [1] => t
       )
[jmlh] => Array
        (
           [0] => 4
           [1] => 6
        )
```

and I want to insert it into a database that will be looked like

```
id   nmbr   jmlh
1    u      4
2    t      6
```

i try using a for loop but it only detect the first array, the second one is not inserted into the database.

this is my for looping

```
$namabarang = $_POST['nmbr'];
$jumlah = $_POST['jmlh'];
for ( $i = 0; $i<$total; $i++)
{
  $nmbr = $namabarang[$i];
  $jmlh = $jumlah[$i];
  $data = array(
    'id_tender' => $primary_key,
        'nmbr' => $nmbr,
        'jumlah' => $jmlh
        );
  $this->db->insert('tb_tender_barang', $data);
}
```

Comment: Where are you specifying `$total` ?

Comment: I think it's not looping "enough" to insert both of them.

Comment: add `$total = (count($namabarang) > count($jumlah)) ? count($namabarang) : count($jumlah);` before the for loop. This is equivalent to saying if `$namabarang` has more elements then $jumlah then set $total to equal the amount of items in `$namabarang` else set item count from `$jumlah`

Comment: if nmbr and jmlh always have the same number of count. You can just use `foreach`

Comment: I forgot to mention >   $total=count($namabarang)    and yes, nmbr and jmlh always have the same number of count, and how do i use foreach because i tried and still get array not the string inside the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both arrays will have the same size. A simple for loop should suffice. In your current code, you didn't check the size of either of them that you used inside the loop. Consider this example:

```
// this will just strictly work if they have the same size!
$namabarang = $_POST['nmbr'];
$jumlah = $_POST['jmlh'];

for($i = 0, $size = count($jumlah); $i < $size; $i++) {
    $data = array('id' => $i+1, 'nmbr' => $nmbr[$i], 'jmlh' => $jmlh[$i]);
    $this->db->insert('tb_tender_barang', $data);
}
```

> Sidenote: Why do you need to manually insert the `id` in the table? Let the `AUTO INCREMENT` handle that for you.

Comment: it works perfect! thankyou kevinabelita :) and yes, i auto increment the id, thank you very much once again :)